# Cognos 10.2 Compatibility With Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, cognos, cognos-10

I'm working in Cognos 10.1.1 and we are planning for Cognos 10.2 upgrade.  We are also planning to upgrade IE to v11.0 .  We have tested 10.1.1 in IE11 but it is not compatible.  The Report Studio tool is stuck though it is said that Report studio works in IE v6.0 and above. If Cognos 10.2 supports IE11, I cannot worry about the IE11 upgrade.  If you are using IE11 and Cognos 10.2, please share your experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for a 3rd party tool.  Contacting the vendor would be the best course of action.

Comment: Or checking the [Compatability Report](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1408125530480&osPlatforms=Windows&duComponentIds=D034|D014|D026|D027|D015|D021|D028|D023|D020|D025|D024|D031|D016|D033|D012|D017|D018|D013|D030|D029|D032|D022|D019|S005|S003|S001|S006|S002|S006|S004|A009|A007|A008|M011|M010).

Comment: My company currently runs IE 10 and Report Studio will only work properly in "compatibility mode". I'm not sure about 11 but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of supported browsers and configurations at the [Supported Environments](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021368) page:

Cognos BI supports IE version 11 for both 10.2 and 10.1.1, so you shouldn't be experiencing any problems.

Remember that for IE versions 10 and 11, you must be in *[Compatibility View](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536204)*.

Report Studio also requires that you have these settings:

- Allow Cookies.
- Active Scripting.
- Allow META REFRESH.
- Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins.
- Binary and script behaviors.
- Allow programmatic clipboard access.
- Enable pop-ups for the IBM Cognos BI server.
- Enable Userdata Persistence

If you're still unable to use Report Studio in IE11 with either 10.1.1 or 10.2, you should log a ticket with Cognos support.

Answer (score 0):

Cognos BI 10.2.1
IE 11.0.9600.17280
Works fine